# Json wont stringify object with api via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

im trying to display these objects from this array but it wont stringify
and it justs prints out [object object], im trying to display the data 
from: priceRanges: Array(1)
0: {type: "standard", currency: "USD", min: 155, max: 750}
length: 1

I made a js fiddel so you can so what it looks like 
https://jsfiddle.net/5faunxv1/

array:[array/api console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxPwW.jpg)

my api key https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events?apikey=y6aYNgQseDLOv5SU0mkdHJydpO8etTgd&locale=*

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
$(function() {


    $.ajax({
        url: "https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events?apikey=y6aYNgQseDLOv5SU0mkdHJydpO8etTgd&locale=*",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);

           console.log(data._embedded.events[1].priceRanges[0]);
     //  var yourval = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data._embedded.events[1].priceRanges[0]));
        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(data._embedded.events[1].priceRanges[0]);


       //     var objectX = JSON.parse(data);
         //   console.log(yourval);
    //     document.write(yourval);
            data._embedded.events.forEach(function(job) {
                var job_text = "event: " + job.name;
                var link = "link: " + data._embedded.events[1].priceRanges;
           // alert(data._embedded.events[1].priceRanges.stringify);  

                $("#result").append("<div style='margin-bottom: 10px;'><div>" + "<h3>" + job_text + "<br>" + link + "</h3>" + "</div><div>" +  "</div></div>")

            })
        }
    });
});


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>OpenWeatherMap Api</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>     

    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Filter Anything</h2>
    <p>Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside the div element with id="myDIV":</p>
    <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">


    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!--
    <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>  
    -->
        <ul id="result"></ul>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There is no such priceRange field in the api response data you provided. Can you get more detail like the exact error being thrown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `console.log(data._embedded.events[1]);` after your first `console.log(data)` you will see that there is no property **priceRanges** :
[image]

Check if the property **priceRanges** exists before access to it.

Comment: i mean this one console.log(data._embedded.events[0]);

Comment: console.log(data._embedded.events[0].priceRanges[0]); gives me this in the console {type: "standard", currency: "USD", min: 155, max: 750}

Comment: it has priceRanges property, its in data._embedded.events[0].priceRanges[0]) not data._embedded.events[1].priceRanges[0]), my bad

Comment: for your `var link`, use this if you want to display something : `var link = "link: " + JSON.stringify(data._embedded.events[0].priceRanges);`